# Proper way to wait for iOS Swift CBPeripheralDelegate to complete?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

When doing Bluetooth communications one is often placed in a situation where one does a call which gets a response in a delegate, for example the characteristic discovery shown below:

```
func discoverCharacteristics(device: CBPeripheral)
{
    servicesCount = device.services!.count

    for service in device.services!
    {
        print("Discovering characteristics for service \(service.uuid)")
        device.discoverCharacteristics([], for: service)
    }
}
```

Now this discovery is not for a specific device but for health devices following the Bluetooth SIG services/profiles, so I don't know exactly what services they might have and I don't know how many characteristics might be in each service. The method is asynchronous and the answers are signaled in the following delegate method:

```
// Discovered Characteristics event
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)
{
    for characteristic in service.characteristics!
    {
        print("Found characteristic \(characteristic.uuid)")
    }
    servicesCount = servicesCount - 1;
    print("Characteristics sets left: \(servicesCount)")
    if servicesCount == 0
    {
        print ("Found all characteristics")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.btleManager!.btleManagerDelegate.statusEvent(device: peripheral, statusEvent: Btle.CHARACTERISTICS_DISCOVERED)
        }
        self.device = peripheral
        self.handleMds()
    }
}
```

Now I need to wait until the discovery is done before I can take the next step because what I do next often depends on what I got. In Java and on Android what I do is wait on a CountDownLatch in the calling method and I signal the latch in the callback to release that wait.

The iOS equivalent of the CountDownLatch seems to be the DispatchSemaphore. However, doing so apparently blocks the system and no delegate ever gets called. SO what I have done (as shown in the code above) is to initialize a variable `servicesCount` with the number of services and in the delegate callback decrement it each time it is signaled. When it gets to zero I am done and then I do the next step.

This approach works but it seems hacky; it can't be correct. And its starting to get really messy when I need to do several reads of the DIS characteristics, the features, the various time services, etc.  **So what I would like to know is  what is the proper method to wait for a delegate to get signaled before moving forward?** Recall I  do not know what services or characteristics these devices might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you already have an implementation with CountDownLatch for Android, you may just do the same implementation for iOS. Yes, Swift doesn't have a built-in `CountDownLatch`, but nice folks from Uber [created a good implementation](https://github.com/uber/swift-concurrency/blob/master/Sources/Concurrency/CountDownLatch.swift).

Another option is to rely on a variable, like you do, but make it atomic. There are various implementations available online, including one in the same Uber library. Another example is in [RxSwift library](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/c1bd31b397d87a54467af4161dde9d6b27720c19/Platform/AtomicInt.swift). There are many other variations. Atomic variable will provide a thread-safety to variable's read/write operations.

But probably the most swifty way is to have a DispatchGroup. Will look something like this:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // instance-level definition

// ...

func discoverCharacteristics
{
    for service in device.services!
    {
        dispatchGroup.enter() 
        // ...
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

        // All done
        print ("Found all characteristics")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.btleManager!.btleManagerDelegate.statusEvent(device: peripheral, statusEvent: Btle.CHARACTERISTICS_DISCOVERED)
        }
        self.device = peripheral
        self.handleMds()
    }

// ...

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)
{
    // ...
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
```

In other words, you enter the group when you are about to submit a request, you leave it when request is processed. When all items left the group, `notify` will execute with the block you provided.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution - if it works - as I did something similar using DispatchSemaphore. After making the call, I entered the wait, and in the delegate, should it get triggered, I released the semaphore. However, doing such caused the delegate never to get called. If this DispatchGroup approach works, I will gladly take it. I still don't understand why the DispatchSemaphore didnt work...I also like the idea because I cannot use any third party libraries.

Comment: @BrianReinhold one gotcha is that `wait` should not block main thread (in other words: `wait` thread should not be called on main thread). For dispatch groups and semaphores it applies in the same way, but as you notice I used `notify` instead of wait, which does not block any thread, it simply is not executed until the condition is true

Comment: Worked like a charm! I must be on the main thread  or UI thread and not realize it. I was trying to emulate an Android Service which is on the main thread but NOT the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You only get a single call to `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor` for each call to `device.discoverCharacteristics`. That is, the `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor` call is only made once all of the service's characteristics have been discovered.

You have the `peripheral` passed to the delegate call, so you have the information you need to know the context of the delegate call.  There is no need to "wait".  You can use a simple state machine per peripheral or service if you are discovering data for multiple peripherals/services simultaneously.

You can even keep a set of peripherals that aren't in a completely discovered state if you need to take some action once discovery is complete; e.g. You can remove a peripheral from the set once discovery is complete for that peripheral. If the set is empty, discovery is complete for all devices.

All of this state belongs in your model.  All your delegate implementation should need to do is update the model with the data that has been discovered.